# Создание приложения для Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Как создать простое клиентское приложение для Reddit, отображающего топ публикации с https://www.reddit.com/top?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `webView.loadUrl("https://www.reddit.com/top");`